# Remove a Value from Multi-Select Picklist through Automation

Tags: process-builder, automation

I am working with Process Builder and am trying to build a criteria that states:

"If the value of one field equals "X" on a record, a value from a multi-select picklist should be removed from the multi-select picklist on the same record"

I can't seem to figure this one out. Am I able to do this through Process Builder or is there a better way of using automation to make this happen. Thanks!

Comment: seems liek the UI is the only way to to delete picklist value from a set.

Comment: I dont think process builder can access metadata. You might be able to call an apex method which adjusts the metadata for a field by calling the metadata api. Modifying metadata would effect all records, however. You might need to move your picklist filtering to a visualforce page instead of trying to modify metadata.

Comment: Convert to Flow and use the UnofficialSF.com multiselect pick list component.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've found, there's no way to do this. You'll need a trigger for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove Multiselect picklist value from the schema itself, then it is not possible.Since Process builder cannot manipulate/modify salesforce meatdata.

Comment: I would like a value in the field to be removed from the record, not metadata.